# Pushing metrics to pushgateway replaces the old one

Tags: java, prometheus-pushgateway

We have a java application called `MonitorApp` that is running in a docker container. The purpose of this app is to perform certain tasks, push the metrics to the `Pushgateway` and die.

This MonitorApp runs **as a `Kubernetes Cron Job`.** This means after publishing matrices, it will get killed and a new instance will come up after some time.

I am using **Java `Pushgateway` APIs** to publish the matrices.
Here is my sample code for the same:

```java
class MonitorApp {

   public void static main(String args[]) {
       
        List<String> labelKeys = Arrays.asList("key01", "key02");
        List<String> labelValues = Arrays.asList("value01", "value01");

        PushGateway client = new PushGateway("localhost:9091");
        CollectorRegistry registry = CollectorRegistry.defaultRegistry;

        String jobName = "midm_monitor_app";
        String metric = "metrin_name";
        String help = "metric_help";


        Counter counter = Counter.build()
                .name(metric)
                .help(help)
                .labelNames(labelKeys.toArray(new String[0]))
                .register(registry);
        counter.labels(labelValues.toArray(new String[0])).inc();

        client.push(registry,jobName);
     }
}
```

The issue is that I am not able to increase the value of the Counter metric.
I am not able to find a way to fetch the previous counter value so that I can increment it.

I have read that purpose of the `Pushgateway` is to handle this kind of use case.

Please suggest how to should I handle this?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want a metric to be increased between multiple run of your instance. This is [not the goal of the push gateway](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway#non-goals): it will only store the values you push - not aggregate them in any way except for add/replace of metrics group.

Although I have never used them, there are solutions to have aggregation using other monitoring stacks (like statd) or specific projects like [pushprom](https://github.com/messagebird/pushprom). You could also push runs as events (in elasticsearch by example) for further aggregation.

If it is really a sensitive part of your application monitoring, I advise you stay away from SPOF solutions. You could roll your own metric cache leveraging any (distributed) key/value store at your disposal.